# JAXB unmarshal Collection (Set)

Tags: collections, jaxb, set, marshalling, unmarshalling

I am testing marshalling and unmarshalling the following Java objects:

Framework class:

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "framework")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
public class Framework implements Comparable<Framework>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlTransient
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String frameworkName;
    private String frameworkVersion;
    private String frameworkDescription;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "framework-domains")
    private Set<FrameworkDomain> frameworkDomainList = new HashSet<>();
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "framework-comments")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
```

(contains only getters, setters and a nuber of functions without any additional annotation)

Domain class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "domain")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
public class FrameworkDomain implements Comparable<FrameworkDomain>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlTransient
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String domainName;
    private String domainDescription;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "domain-requirements")
    private Set<Requirement> domainRequirements = new HashSet<>();
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "domain-comments")
    private Set<Comment> domainComments = new HashSet<>();
```

Requirement class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "requirement")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Entity
public class Requirement implements Comparable<Requirement>, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlTransient
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String requirementName;
    private String requirementDescription;
    private String requirementGuidance;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "sub-requirements")
    private Set<Requirement> requirementSubrequirementList = new HashSet<>();
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "testing-procedures")
    private Set<TestingProcedure> requirementTestingProceduresList = new HashSet<>();
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "requirement-comments")
    private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();
```

Marshalling and unmarshaling code:

```
public static String exportFramework(Framework f) {
    java.io.StringWriter s = new java.io.StringWriter();
    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Framework.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "utf-8");
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        marshaller.marshal(f, s);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return s.toString();
}

public static Framework importFramework(java.io.InputStream xml) {
    intelicompliance.model.Framework f = null;

    try {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Framework.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        f = (intelicompliance.model.Framework) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
    } catch (JAXBException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return f;
}
```

When I marshal an object I have created, it generates the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<framework>
    <frameworkName>PCI DSS</frameworkName>
    <frameworkVersion>3.3</frameworkVersion>
    <frameworkDescription>The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) is a proprietary information security standard for organizations that handle branded credit cards from the major card schemes including Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover, and JCB.</frameworkDescription>
    <framework-domains>
        <frameworkDomainList>
            <domainName>Domain 1a</domainName>
            <domainDescription>Build and Maintain a Secure Network and Systems</domainDescription>
            <domain-requirements></domain-requirements>
            <domain-comments></domain-comments>
        </frameworkDomainList>
        <frameworkDomainList>
            <domainName>Domain 2a</domainName>
            <domainDescription>Protect Cardholder Data</domainDescription>
            <domain-requirements/>
            <domain-comments/>
        </frameworkDomainList>
        <frameworkDomainList>
            <domainName>Domain 3a</domainName>
            <domainDescription>Maintain a Vulnerability Management Program</domainDescription>
            <domain-requirements/>
            <domain-comments/>
        </frameworkDomainList>
        <frameworkDomainList>
            <domainName>Domain 4a</domainName>
            <domainDescription>Implement Strong Access Control Measures</domainDescription>
            <domain-requirements/>
            <domain-comments/>
        </frameworkDomainList>
        <frameworkDomainList>
            <domainName>Domain 5a</domainName>
            <domainDescription>Regularly Monitor and Test Networks</domainDescription>
            <domain-requirements/>
            <domain-comments/>
        </frameworkDomainList>
        <frameworkDomainList>
            <domainName>Domain 6a</domainName>
            <domainDescription>Maintain an Information Security Policy</domainDescription>
            <domain-requirements/>
            <domain-comments/>
        </frameworkDomainList>
    </framework-domains>
    <framework-comments/>
</framework>
```

... which is exactly what I am expecting.

However, when I try to convert the XML back into the object, only one of the domains is included in the Set - i.e. the import (unmarshalling) process ignores XML nodes after the first one.

Does anyone has an idea why? Or, what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I have made some progress by changing:

```
private Set<FrameworkDomain> frameworkDomainList = new HashSet<>();
```

to:

```
private List<FrameworkDomain> frameworkDomainList = new LinkedList<>();
```

which now imports all children elements as expected. However, I really prefer to use Set.

Does JAXB treats Set(s) different from List(s)?

Comment: Did you properly set the hashCode() methods in your objects ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "properly"... here is the code:
@Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my question :

What i meant by properly is that you ensured that every object that are not the same will return a different hash.

Your problem is coming from the fact that every object you're unmarshalling have the same hashCode, hence your set think that every elements are equals, and only keep one (the last one JAXB processes, incidentally the first one).

You should be able to confirm this behavior by adding into an HashSet your objects without ids, only the last one should be kept.

It also explain why your list is populated when you're switching to a linked list.

Either use a different hashCode method or marshall the ids to resolve  your problem.

Keep in mind that you should always override the equals() method alongside the hashCode() method, and ensure that a.equals(b) and a.hashCode == b.hashCode always yield the same results.

Comment: You, my friend, is a scholar and gentlemen! You have pinpointed the issue and the suggested solution!